# Dagger hilt errror "lateinit property has not been initialized"

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am trying to inject a class in my fragment using field injection by it is giving me UninitializedPropertyAccessException when I try to access it in `onViewCreated()`. How can I fix this?

Class I am trying to inject:

```kotlin
@Singleton
class DialogHandler @Inject constructor() {

    private var currentDialogKey = "dialog_key"
    //....
    //....
}
```

My fragment:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AccountFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_account) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dialogHandler: DialogHandler

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val currentDialogKey = dialogHandler.currentDialogKey // throws error saying dialogHandler is uninitialized
        //....
        //....
    }
}
```

Hilt has been setup correctly in the app and is working fine with constructor injection in other classes. But since constructor injection is not possible for fragments, I tried using field injection and got this error.
Please help.

**Edit:** This exception doesn't occur everytime. So it seems like this is a case of race condition where sometimes `onViewCreated()` is called before injection and sometimes after injection.

Comment: Where do you have the provider for `DialogHandler`? add it with Question

Comment: To make it more clear to what @ADM is asking, please add your `@Module` file where you are providing (initializing) the `DialogHandler` Object.

Comment: @hsm59 I don't think he even has an module , as he is annotating with `@Singleton` on the go.

Comment: @Anshul, Yes, it seems like it.

Comment: @ADM Can u plz explain why is a `@Module` required here? I use that only for providing interfaces or for classes that I don't own.

Comment: Write a `@Provide` method to provide `DialogHandler` in your module which is annotated with  `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class).
`

Comment: I have a class for that purpose but I use it to provide instance for my RoomDatabase, repository etc. `@Provides` is needed when hilt is not sure how to  create instance of that particular type. This isn't the case here. Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#hilt-modules

Comment: To be clear, you are NOT required to have a module if your dependency can be provided via constructor injection (as OP does in this example). Even if you didn't, you'd receive a *compile time* error pointing out that a binding is missing. Runtime issues indicate that a class is not actually being injected anywhere (at runtime), so you should double check your hilt setup / entry points and make sure it's working as intended.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak As I mentioned in the edit, this issue occurs at random occasions and not every-time. BTW is there any fixed point of time when hilt injects dependencies, like for an Activity field injected properties are available after `super.onCreate()` call. Is there any such point in case of fragments as well?

Comment: I just wanted to say the bit about runtime/compile time issues since there seems to be a lot of confusion about modules.
I've not used Hilt yet so I'm not of much help here, but I believe it happens all in onAttach (if it happens) before onCreate and by the time of `onViewCreated` it should definitely be available. So if it's still uninitialized there then I would assume it wasn't going to happen at all and that you have some general issue with your setup

Comment: are you using the latest hilt version? 
Can you show us the hilt dependencies of your gradle files?

Comment: @gts13
Project level gradle:
hilt_version = '2.38.1'
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"

App level gradle:
plugins {
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

Comment: yes, dependencies are ok. 
Do you inject other classes in the `DialogHandler`?

Comment: No, it does not have any other dependencies.